# C/C++ Structure offset

Tags: c++, c, oop

I'm looking for a piece of code that can tell me the offset of a field within a structure without allocating an instance of the structure.

IE: given

```
struct mstct {
    int myfield;
    int myfield2;
};
```

I could write:

```
mstct thing;
printf("offset %lu\n", (unsigned long)(&thing.myfield2 - &thing));
```

And get `offset 4` for the output. How can I do it without that `mstct thing` declaration/allocating one?

I know that `&<struct>` does not always point at the first byte of the first field of the structure, I can account for that later.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

How about the standard offsetof() macro (in stddef.h)?

Edit: for people who might not have the offsetof() macro available for some reason, you can get the effect using something like:

```
#define OFFSETOF(type, field)    ((unsigned long) &(((type *) 0)->field))
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted, because I don't have stddef.h, but it does answer my question with: #define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)

Comment: Wow - no stddef.h?  Just out of curiosity, could I ask what you're using?

Comment: It's in the C99 standard, so I'd suggest getting a new compiler.

Comment: more than that - it's been in C since ANSI C89.  I have no idea how common (or uncommon) it was pre-standard.

Comment: I once had a C compiler that had offsetof() defined in stddef.h with the zero trick, but it also didn't allow the use of zero as a base address.  (Long time ago - 1989, or thereabouts.)  Workaround was to change 0 to 1024 instead.

Answer (score 9):

Right, use the `offsetof` macro, which (at least with GNU CC) is available to both C and C++ code:

```
offsetof(struct mstct, myfield2)
```

Comment: offsetof() has been in standard C/C++ since the first ANSI C89 standard.  Every compiler should have it, unless you're using something seriously ancient.  Even then it could be cobbled together using ugly casting & pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Agreed - I'd most likely provide a dummy <stddef.h> to provide that macros.  Plauger provides "The Standard C Library" and it is an easy header to provide - as long as it does not have to be portable.

Comment: AFAIK, offsetof() is not hing *but* ugly casting & pointer arithmetic... something like:

#define offsetof(type, field) ((char *)&(((type *)0)->field) - (char *)0)

Answer (score 3):

printf("offset: %d\n", &((mstct*)0)->myfield2);

Comment: Apart from the fact that `offsetof` does this in a more readable way, you can't generally print a `ptrdiff_t` with `%d` -- on LP64 systems, it's too large.