# C/C++ nullptr dereference

Tags: c++, c, null, nullptr

Since de-referencing `nullptr` (`NULL`) is an undefined behavior both in `C` and `C++`, I am wondering if expression `&(*ptr)` is a valid one if ptr is `nullptr` (`NULL`).

If it is also an undefined behavior, how does [OFFSETOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/142023) macro in the linked answer work?

I always thought that `ptr->field` is a shorthand for `(*ptr).field`

I think the answer to my question is similar in C and C++.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators 3
The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ‘‘type’’,
the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. If the operand is the result of a unary * operator,
neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were
omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.*

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate, but be sure to read the discussion under the C++ answer, as well as [this discussion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232), as this is not quite so explicit in the C++ standard.

Comment: I doubt this is duplicate as OP asks "if dereferencing `nullptr` is UB how offesetof works"

Comment: Thank you @TartanLlama. I read that topic and will read it again. It was just not clear what question was asked and was the correct answer to that question. It looks more like discussion :-)

Comment: @TartanLlama Since I can't find an equivalent exemption for using `&*NULL` in c++, I suspect this may be one of the points where the two languages diverge. The supposed duplicate can only stand if the `c`-tag is removed.

Comment: @EOF I'm not sure what you mean; that question has answers addressing C and C++.

Comment: The dupe is wrong.... Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/7346634/560648? Depends on the language though. I wish the OP would bloomin' pick one.

Comment: @TartanLlama: If you read my first comment here, you'll notice that **there is no `NULL`-dereference** if the code is treated as C. Therefore, answers explaining undefinedness of `NULL`-dereference are not suitable as duplicates.

Comment: @EOF Ah yes, my mistake, ignore my silliness.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Nope, that's not right either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The problem is that OP asked four questions. OP should pick one question so people can give the answer to it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: And at least one of them, as far as I can tell, differs between C and C++, in contradiction to the OP's assertion that the answers would be similar for the two languages.

Comment: I am not sure why the question was marked as duplicate to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383684/is-there-a-platform-or-situation-where-dereferencing-but-not-using-a-null-poin)? I am wondering if my example is an undefined behavior (and how `offsetof` works if it is). The question above already **gives** an example of undefined behavior and is about the platform. These two questions are completely different. I think I am very specific in mine. How can I reformulate it?

Comment: @Trula I think answer to your question is "implementation of standard library does not have to be valid C or C++ code and discussing if implementation itself there is standard complaint is useless".

Comment: The identified duplicate does not answer this question.

Comment: The C standards, since the 1989 ANSI standard all specify that `&*ptr` has well defined behaviour, since result (in such expression) effectively discards both the `&` and the `*`.   Not sure, offhand, what the C++ standards have to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR `&(*(char*)0)` is well defined.

The C++ standard doesn't say that indirection of null pointer by itself has UB. Current standard draft, [[expr.unary.op]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op)

> 1. The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression is “pointer to T”, the type of the result is “T”. [snip]
> 2. The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id. [snip]

There is no UB unless the lvalue of the indirection expression is converted to an rvalue.

---

The C standard is much more explicit. C11 standard draft §6.5.3.2

> 3. The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type "type", the  result  has  type  "pointer to type". **If the  operand  is  the  result  of  a unary * operator, neither  that  operator  nor  the & operator  is  evaluated  and  the  result  is  as  if  both  were omitted**, except  that  the  constraints  on  the  operators  still  apply  and  the  result  is  not  an lvalue.  Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the  unary * that  is  implied  by  the [] is  evaluated  and  the  result  is  as  if  the
>    & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator. Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.

Answer (score 1):

> If it is also an undefined behavior, how does `offsetof` work?

Prefer using [the standard `offsetof` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). Home-grown versions result in compiler warnings. Moreover:

> `offsetof` is required to work as specified above, even if unary `operator&` is overloaded for any of the types involved. This cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support.

`offsetof` is a [built-in function in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html).

Comment: OP is referring to the macro from the link: #define OFFSETOF(type, field)    ((unsigned long) &(((type *) 0)->field))

Comment: @Byteventurer No reason to use a home-grown `offsetoff`, it results in compiler warnings. Use the standard  [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: I am not propagating the use of the macro, I am explaining what the OP is referring to when asking the question...

Comment: @Byteventurer I think the OP is confusing `offsetof` with `OFFSETOF`. `offsetof` is an identifier reserved for the implementation, whereas `OFFSETOF` could be anything.

Comment: Perhaps he is. Still, the question was about &(*p) where p is a null pointer, not about offsetof itself, and the offsetof macro he linked to did just that. Before the edit, you missed the point of the question IMO.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I am aware that `offsetof` and `OFFSETOF` are different. Nevertheless, the question was not about which one to use. `OFFSETOF` was just a simple example with `64` upvotes and marked as an accepted answer. I can give another [example](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/stddef.h) if that would be more convenient ;-)